# How to create desktop shortcut for all users in WIX

Tags: installation, wix, shortcut

I am developping a MSI installer by using WIX, I can create shortcut on desktop for only one user. Now what shall I do to make a shortcut for all users on the machine? Please advise. Thank you.

```
<Shortcut Id="desktopshortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="test" 
          WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Advertise="yes" />
```

Comment: What context are you installing in? Per-user or per-machine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can have WiX set `ALLUSERS=1` automatically by declaring `Package/@InstallScope='perMachine'`... e.g.

```
<Package Description="!(loc.Package_Description) $(var.version)"
   Comments="!(loc.Package_Comments)"
   Manufacturer="!(loc.ManufacturerName)"
   InstallerVersion="301"
   Compressed="yes"
   InstallPrivileges="elevated"
   InstallScope="perMachine"
   Platform="$(var.ProcessorArchitecture)" />
```

Comment: I think some more context is in order for users who find this. **ALLUSERS** affects a number of things in a setup, most of which I find to be counter-intuitive and frankly detrimental. Please read about [**MSI Installation Context**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn what folders are redirected for a per-user install, and what other things to look out for. Check the documentation for the [**ALLUSERS property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) itself as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set `ALLUSERS=1`, so that the Installer points the [`DesktopFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368276(VS.85).aspx) property to the common desktop instead of the installing user's desktop.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but seems it doesn't work. It says ALLUSERS attribute is not declared after I add it into my code. Is there anything else I need to add? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ensure it's added in as <Property Id="ALLUSERS">1</Property> under your Product.

Comment: The element 'Product' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' has invalid child element 'Property' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'.